# Liquibase Cannot find ChangeLogHistoryService for oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, liquibase

Recently, in my machine, every time I try to load a java project with Liquibase I get the error

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.UnexpectedLiquibaseException: Cannot find ChangeLogHistoryService for oracle
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory.getChangeLogService(ChangeLogHistoryServiceFactory.java:73)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.checkLiquibaseTables(Liquibase.java:724)
```

I can't find any information on this, beyond the source file.
All I know is that the same project, with the same source code seems to work on other computers. As far as I can tell, all configs are the same.

Any idea on what might cause this issue in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

It means that one of the tables that Liquibase expects to find in the database (liquibasechangelog or liquibasechangeloglock) has been removed. If it is working on other machines it probably means that the database you are connecting to is also different. It sounds like you might be trying to connect to the database on localhost, which would explain the difference.

Comment: I thought of that too, and the tables are there.

Answer (score 1):

The error looks more like a classloader issue. Liquibase has a plug-in system that relies on finding class implementations in the classpath, including the built-in classes. Liquibase is looking for an implementation of ChangeLogHistoryService that support oracle and it isn't finding the liquibase.changelog.StandardChangeLogHistoryService class that it should be.

Are there any earlier errors you are seeing? If you run liquibase with logLevel=DEBUG it may also output better clues as to the cause of the unfound class.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the liquibase version (from 3.1.1) to 3.2.0 and the problem went away.

I did have to fix SOME of the checksome codes in DATABASECHANGELOG table (3 records in 16). The fact that it wasn´t all of them may point to a possible origin for the problem? maybe?

For now everything works fine with the new version. If the problem comes up again in the future I will look into this again.

Thank you all for your support.